# Entering a finite seminar in org mode

Tags: org-agenda

This

```
* Charles's seminar
  <2018-08-21 Tue 10:00-12:00+1w>
```

is a seminar repeated every week.  But it doesn't go on forever.
How do I set an end date?

Comment: This should be possible by setting a deadline on the item, and setting `org-agenda-skip-scheduled-if-deadline-is-shown` to `repeated-after-deadline`, but that doesn't work for me in Org 9.1.13

Comment: @rpluim, that's odd, doesn't work for me either.

Answer (score 1):

So you can do this using `diary` date commands as follows:

```
* Charles's seminar 10:00-12:00
  <%%(and (= 2 (calendar-day-of-week date)) (diary-block 7 30 2018 8 14 2018))>
```

I don't find that very elegant, but it works. Be aware that `diary-block` month/day parameter interpretation depends on the value of `calendar-date-style`.

It turns out that there is an elegant way to do it:

```
* Charles's seminar 10:00-12:00
  <%%(org-class 2018 7 30 2018 8 14 2)>
```

where year/month/day are always in ISO8601 order.